# Defining Monad Function?

Tags: j

```
v=: ((1 2);(3 4);(0 5);<(2 1))
d =: (1,0.5,1,0.25);(0.5,1,0.75,0.25);(1,0.75,1,0);(0.75,0.25,0,1)
force=:(v ((0{>"0 v);])@{~ ] i.4) ,"1 0 <"0>(0{d)
force=:(v ((1{>"0 v);])@{~ ] i.4) ,"1 0 <"0>(1{d)
force=:(v ((2{>"0 v);])@{~ ] i.4) ,"1 0 <"0>(2{d)
force=:(v ((3{>"0 v);])@{~ ] i.4) ,"1 0 <"0>(3{d)
force=:(v ((4{>"0 v);])@{~ ] i.4) ,"1 0 <"0>(4{d)
force=:(v ((y{>"0 v);])@{~ ] i.4) ,"1 0 <"0>(y{d)
```

Given v and d, 
  1st column of force gives us (n+1)th vector from v.

2nd column of force gives us each vector from v.

3rd column of force gives us a constant between 2 vectors.

That is, `(1 2);(1 2)` will have 1 on 3rd column of force, but `(1 2);(3 4)` might not.
  I want to make a monad function which gives us

`force=:(v ((1{>"0 v);])@{~ ] i.4) ,"1 0 <"0>(1{d)`

if we type `force_constant 1`

or `force=:(v ((2{>"0 v);])@{~ ] i.4) ,"1 0 <"0>(2{d)`

if we type `force_constant 2`

Could someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote most of it yourself already. Just take your final version of `force`, the one you wrote using `y`, and wrap it in an explicit definition:

```
    v =:  ((1 2);(3 4);(0 5);<(2 1))
    d =:  (1,0.5,1,0.25);(0.5,1,0.75,0.25);(1,0.75,1,0);(0.75,0.25,0,1)

   force_constant =: monad def '(v ((y{>"0 v);])@{~ ] i.4) ,"1 0 <"0>(y{d)'

   force_constant 1
+---+---+----+
|3 4|1 2|0.5 |
+---+---+----+
|3 4|3 4|1   |
+---+---+----+
|3 4|0 5|0.75|
+---+---+----+
|3 4|2 1|0.25|
+---+---+----+

   force_constant 2
+---+---+----+
|0 5|1 2|1   |
+---+---+----+
|0 5|3 4|0.75|
+---+---+----+
|0 5|0 5|1   |
+---+---+----+
|0 5|2 1|0   |
+---+---+----+
```

Now, this formulation depends on the nouns `v` and `d` being globally defined. You might consider changing that so `force_constant` or related verbs take these arrays as inputs. The simplest method would be change the monads to dyads, and let `v` and `d` come in as the left argument, `x`¹.

---

¹<sub>But we can keep it simple for now. If you want more feedback on your code, feel free to post it over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.</sub>

Comment: I'd second Dan's suggestion you investigate code review. To give an example this version is a pure simplification of the verb above without investigating tacit or providing `v` & `d` as arguments: `force_constant=: monad def '((y{v) ,. v) ,. <"0 > y{d'`

Comment: @Tikkanz I'd be tempted to go further than that and ditch the boxes. Make it an M x N x 2 array of integers. Add a dummy column (`0`s) to the distance plane to make it regular.